# SPO 2013 - How to enable RTF in our calendar event description field?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, rich-text

Is it possible to modify the default description field in Sharepoint Online calendar to support rich text formatting (RTF)? Our users have been giving us feedback about not being able to make paragraphs in the calendar event descriptions.

We have tried to go into the calendar's settings and modify the default "Description" column but it doesn't really contain any modification options other than the name or so.

Any solutions on how to do this easily? I know one method is just to create a new column that has the RTF enabled but that means all the current events would lose the descriptions because of getting replaced by the new description field. This is why we would like to find a solution just to enable the RTF for the existing description column.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem which I solved partly. I hid the default description field and added various custom fields. Then I added a workflow which creates the default description from the custom fields and additional html tags. This works mostly. Sometimes however, the generated calendar entries are displayed as html source codes, mostly they look ok. This also varies when using another client pc.

So outlook accepts html tags in the description. I did not manage to get this in a stable manner.

Perhaps this may help?